# Dados da API não estão sendo mostrados no console (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu tenho um endpoint que me retorna um array :

```
 consultExams(registerNumber: string): Promise<Exam[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<Exam[]>(`${environment.ecpApiUrl}/subscriptions/exams`, {
        params: { registerNumber },
        headers: this.auth.buildHeaders(),
      })
      .toPromise();
  }
```

Eu preciso pegar um dado de um exame, mas não estou conseguindo. Esse me `endpoint` está vindo de uma classe `ActivitiesSubscriptionsService`

Preciso criar uma função, pois vou usar ela em outro lugar. Estou tentando buscar da seguinte maneira:

```
async validateExam(registerNumber) {
    const result = await this.activitiesSubscriptionsService.consultExams(
      registerNumber
    );
    console.log(result);
}
```

No console não me retorna nenhum, só retorna os erros

Answer (score 0):

Falta fazer um then() para caso seja success e um catch() para caso venha erro.

```js
async validateExam(registerNumber) {
  await this.activitiesSubscriptionsService.consultExams(
    registerNumber
  ).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  });
}
```